# Configure tomcat localhost_access_log externally

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat6

is it possible to change the location of tomcats `logs/localhost_access_log.*` log file, without changing the server.xml file?

Best solution would be a SystemProperty or environment variable. I just don't want to change the default tomcat installation of this, because I roll out dozens of tomcat to diffent hosts, which makes this a tiring and error-prone process.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by taking the following steps:

- On deployment a context file is generated in `tomcat_home/conf/Catalina/localhost/<contextpath>.xml`:

  < Context path="/contextpath">
          < Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
             rotatable="false"
             directory="/the/directory/to/log/to"
             prefix="access_log"
             suffix=".log"
             pattern="combined"
      />
- cron that removed the `tomcat_home/logs/localhost_access_log.*.txt`files, since the Context/Valve-configuration is only additive and doesn't overwrites an existing AccessLogValve.

I know that this writes the logfile twice, and you have to know your contextpath, both is not a problem for my usecase. Another option is to remove the complete Valve tag in the server.xml (it changes the server.xml but is easy to automate).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. Details given below -
1 Create catalina.properties in conf folder
2 Create variable within the file

```
accesslog.file=my_access_log_file
```

3 Reference it in server.xml as

```
directory="logs"  prefix="${accesslog.file}" suffix=".log"
```

Comment: Hi, I know that I could add SystemProperties in the server.xml file, but the trick is, could I change the location _without_ changing theserver.xml file, as described above?

Comment: I dont see how, since the default server.xml points to a hardcoded file name.